# React libraries for create draggable elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draggable

I wanted a React Library with hooks to create a kind of draggable board, like this example:https://rerenote.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use `react-draggable`.

Module Link - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable